# what is the difference and when to choose betweens php with mysql or sqlite for android development?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to android development. and confuse a little bit between two types of databases Mysql and SQLite.

I just need to know when to use SQLite and Mysql with PHP.

Comment: If you want to store data in android you only use sqlite but if you load data from the web to your app you can use the two types, because android only Works with sqlite database to store data local.

Comment: Although not specific to Android many answers can be found here [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html). This even includes a checklist with 3 reasons why you would opt for a client/server (e.g. MySQL/PHP) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well in the android point of view. Android has an inbuilt Phone database which is SQLITE So if You want to store data in  android on the phone .YOu will use the SQLIte database and you will connect to it in Java. MySQL in this case is an external(remote) database that you will connect to remotely via PHP using webservices from the android phone.